# shifting left and then immediately shifting right in asm?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-shift

disclaimer : I'm an asm newbie. I probably need to review my 2s complement or something to fully comprehend :(

I'm confused as to the purpose of the following:

```
....
BL some_func
MOV R3, R0,LSL#16
MOVS R3, R3,LSR#16
....
```

why the shift back? and the movs?

Comment: http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs201/2003/mirrorWebster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_asm/ArtofAssembly/ch15/CH15-2.html#HEADING2-1

Comment: @borealid - thanks, Ive been looking for actual courseware on asm
@starblue it is arm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left-shift, the bits overflowed will be lost. So all bits above 32-16 = 16th digit will be zeroed out after right-shift.

```
     r0 =                   aaaabbbbccccdddd eeeeffffgggghhhh
lsl, 16 -> aaaabbbbccccdddd eeeeffffgggghhhh 0000000000000000
             (overflowed)
        ->                  eeeeffffgggghhhh 0000000000000000
lsr, 16 ->                                   eeeeffffgggghhhh
```

The instruction is equivalent to

```
r3 = r0 & 0xffff;
```

Comment: that mostly answers my question ... at least the one I asked ;)

One piece of data I left out was that r0 is a small value at that point so I dont see what is gained ... ive updated the question

Answer (score 3):

it takes three instructions to do a r0 &= 0xFFFF

```
mov r3,#0x00FF
orr r3,r3,#0xFF00
and r0,r0,r3
```

So the shift back and forth is more efficient.

What you may have been doing is something related to a 16 bit variable so to be accurate the compiler has to truncate the upper bits to make the program operate properly.  had you used int or something it may not have done this, not sure if that is how you instigated these instructions.

Sometimes you will see this to do a sign extension but this was not an arithmetic shift it was a logical shift (zeros coming in not the carry bit).

Maybe your code did something like  if(hello&0xFFFF) then.

ARM does not update the flags normally unless you tell it to, for performance reasons if nothing else  code like this

```
if(a&0xFF) b=0x12; else b=0x34;
would be something like:
ands r0,r0,#0xFF
movne r1,#0x12
moveq r1,#0x34
```

With other processors the and would always set the flags and the next instruction would be a branch causing a pipe flush.

```
ands r0,r0,#0xFF
bne notequal
mov r1,#0x12
b wasequal
notequal:
mov r1,#0x34
wasequal:
```

Much more brutal when executed.  Many processors would overwrite the flags with the move immediate as well, which the arm doesnt do.  (thumb mode is another story).

Instead of only branches having a conditional field, every instruction on the arm has a conditional field, branch if equal, and if equal, add if equal, sub if equal, branch if carry set, and if carry set, etc.  And likewise the instructions that can modify flags have an opcode bit that enables or disables the update of the flags.   You add the s to the instruction.  and r0,r1,r2 does not but ands r0,r1,r2 does update the flags.

So your two instructions did two things it zeroed out the upper 16 bits of a register then set the flags for whatever conditional that followed.  For a mov that was likely a branch if equal or branch if not equal.  What did your originally source code look like that generated this?

Comment: thanks for the detailed response...im still trying to grok it all ... i didn't write the original code, it is the result of a disassembly